# React.js - How do I submit a form on page load?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a form and need to load it when the page loads:

```
<form name="myform" method="POST" className={classes.root} target="mydiv" 
    action="https://example.com/submit" onLoad={() => (this.submit())} >
```

I expect `mydiv` to be populated with the form result when the page loads (like it does when I click my submit button) but it doesn't. What is the trick?

Comment: are you using function or class component?

Comment: Are you getting results from api? Because form data will be empty when page loads and you may get error.

Comment: Why do you want to submit a form on page load? I only ask because maybe there's a better solution to your problem (like just making an ajax call to get some data to populate myDiv)

Comment: I am using react functions. @BoussadjraBrahim

Comment: I am getting results from an API. There is no error. Subsequent calls to the API succeed just fine when I explicitly hit the "Submit" button @RahulGurujala

Comment: The form holds configuration information. When the form is submitted there is a preview shown in an iframe and I'd like to load that iframe on page load rather than have a blank space @Barryman9000

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a ref to your form and submit it when the component is mounted using useEffect hook:

```
import {useRef,useEffect} from 'react'

....

let form=useRef();

useEffect(()=>{
  form.current.submit();
},[])
....
<form name="myform" ref={form} method="POST" className={classes.root} target="mydiv" action="https://example.com/submit"  >
```

Comment: That worked perfectly! Tried to upvote but I don't have enough rep.

Comment: I tried that but I get a loop with the useEffect

Comment: @quielfala what do you mean by loop?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim , I'm getting an infinite loop, page continously reloads. My code is like this, if you can check please. Thanks

 `useEffect(() => {
    form.current.submit()
  }, [])

  return (
    <div>
      {uid} {token}
      <form ref={form}>
        <button type="submit" method="POST" onSubmit={() => console.log('hey')}>
          Butane
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  )`

Comment: It's hard to read the code and it's harder to figure out the issue, please post a new question and give me the link and I'll try to help you

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim, sorry I'm trying to format the code in the comment , I cannot seem to do so

Comment: if you remove `{uid} {token}` do you get rid off this issue?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248012/discussion-between-quielfala-and-boussadjra-brahim).

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim, seems like I don't have the submit() when I console log my ref